# Thymeleaf - skip table creation if the iterated list is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an html thymeleaf template where I build a table iterating over a list:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Setup Name</th>
            <th>Setup Path</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="setup : ${upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups.setups}">
            <td th:text="${setup.name}"/>
            <td th:text="${setup.path}"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The problem is that the element `upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups` may be `null`, so I would like to build this table only when the element is not null.

> Note: if the element `upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups` is not `null`, then it's guaranteed for the list `setups` to be not null either. Hence I only need to check for the parent element.

I have tried to use the `th:if` statement as follows:

```
<tr th:if=${upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups != null} th:each="setup : ${upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups.setups}">
```

But even like that, I still get the same exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'setups' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
    ... 74 more
```

I didn't manage to find a specific example/reference about Thymeleaf for such issue, could anyone please suggest the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count on Thymeleaf [Attribute Precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence). According to the order, Thymeleaf will parse iteration first and only after the condition, when placed into the same tag. The code which would work for you may look like ...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Setup Name</th>
        <th>Setup Path</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody th:if=${upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups != null}>
    <tr th:each="setup : ${upgradeState.targetUpgradeSetups.setups}">
        <td th:text="${setup.name}"/>
        <td th:text="${setup.path}"/>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You were right, it worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: I suggested a small edit. Can you check it? :)

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara Hi Rukshan, I would prefer to leave the example as is without removing the explicit chack for `null`, because this is how OP tested the object. I would assume OP would like to make an explicit check for readability. So be it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara  I don't like very much the way of testing pointers, I find it confusing (you don't know if you're testing for null or if you're testing a Boolean). It's good to know thanks a lot for the suggestion, but I prefer indeed to leave the explicit check :)